# Sendbird video call Integration with iOS Swift

Tags: swift, callkit, sendbird, cxprovider, sendbird-ios

I am trying to integrate `Sendbird` with iOS in swift. Outgoing call is working fine for me. I am not getting any Push for incoming calls. neither of the delegate methods of `cxproviderdelegate` are not getting called. Can any one help me to understand how to implement the same?

I have uploaded all the voip and push notification certificates on sendBird portal. Same certificates are working fine with FCM for receiving push from FCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rishi,

Typically when we see issues with push notifications for iOS, it stems from a few things.

1. The APNs .p12 certificate was not uploaded to the dashboard. You mention you've done this but are testing with FCM. We require the APNs Certs for our Swift SDK.
2. The iOS Device is not registering the User Token to Sendbird (Can be checked by looking at Users > { User } > Push Notification

If you have not already, I'd highly take a look at the [iOS Calls Sample App](https://github.com/sendbird/quickstart-calls-ios) and compare its implementation to yours.

Unfortunately without a lot more information it's difficult to guide you on how to properly implement iOS Calls in Swift. You may consider utilizing their Community for more back and forth conversations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I had done both the above steps. I tried running the sample code provided by sendbird (QuickStart) but the same is not running on my device. I tried to call via their sample app and that is working fine.

Can you let me know what info you need. I can share if I can

Comment: I'd need your APP_ID but I'd prefer not to have you post in publicly. Can you provide me the exact name of your organization in Sendbird? I can locate your APP_ID there.

Comment: Shared with you. Please check your inbox @tyler

Comment: hey @tyler 
am getting error "NotAuthenticated

1800303

The user is not authenticated."